# Enable pressure detection of touchpad

Tags: touchpad

I get a lot of spurious taps on my touchpad that cause me to drag things around and cause me to click things I never meant to click. I think the reason is that the pressure detection (that I assume my touchpad has) is not supported. Is there something I can do to enable it?

```
$ libinput measure touchpad-pressure 
Using SYNACD3E:00 06CB:CD3E Touchpad: /dev/input/event6

This device does not have the capabilities for pressure-based touch detection.
Details: Device does not have ABS_PRESSURE or ABS_MT_PRESSURE
```

I’ve deactivated tap dragging for now, but it’s a feature I usually use all the time and I still get the spurious clicks.

```
xinput list-props 13
Device 'SYNACD3E:00 06CB:CD3E Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (169):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (171): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (322): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (323): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (324):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (325):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (326):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (327):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (328):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (329):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (306):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (307):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (330):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (331):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (308):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (309):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (310):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (332): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (333):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (334):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (335):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (336):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (313): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (314): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (318): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (319): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (291): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (292):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (293):    0, 0
    Device Node (294):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Device Product ID (295):    1739, 52542
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (320):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (321):   1
```

I have the Lenovo IdeaPad S540 and libinput version 1.15.5.

Is there some way to install the right driver for the touchpad or something else I can do to get pressure or size detection?

Comment: Extremely annoyingly, there seems to be very little user control on this. I have the same concern.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was solved by switching to synaptics:

`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

(Then log out and log in again.)

Untested: Another alternative would’ve been:

`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev`